# Can't Connect to Kafka running on Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I deployed Kafka using Docker Compose to a server but I am unable to connect to Kafka. I used the bitnami/kafka images.

```
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/master/docker-compose.yml > docker-compose.yml
$ docker-compose up -d
```

Using Kafka Tool I've tried connecting to Zookeeper and using bootstrap to try connecting directly to Kafka. It always times out however I have verified I can hit port 2181 and 9092 on the docker host and ping from Kafka tool works as well which leads me to believe those services are up and listening removing the possibility of firewall/network issues.

[image]

My docker compose file

```
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:3'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    volumes:
      - 'zookeeper_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:2'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '9093:9093'
    volumes:
      - 'kafka_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Please share the connection string used. Error message if any

Comment: Try Conduktor instead. You don't need to use Zookeeper connection details